# How to use std::string_view::remove_prefix() on a constexpr string_view

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

`std::string_view::remove_prefix()` and `std::string_view::remove_suffix()` are both `constexpr` member functions in c++17; however, they modify the variable on which they are called. If the value is `constexpr`, it will also be `const` and cannot be modified, so how can these functions be used on a `constexpr` value?

To put it another way:

```
constexpr std::string_view a = "asdf";
a.remove_prefix(2); // compile error- a is const
```

How do you use these functions on a `constexpr std::string_view`? If they can't be used on a `constexpr std::string_view`, why are the functions themselves marked `constexpr`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason they're marked `constexpr` is so you can use them within a `constexpr` function, e.g.:

```
constexpr std::string_view remove_prefix(std::string_view s) {
    s.remove_prefix(2);
    return s;
}

constexpr std::string_view b = remove_prefix("asdf"sv);
```

If `remove_prefix()` weren't `constexpr`, this would be an error.

---

That said, I would write:

```
constexpr std::string_view a = "asdf"sv.substr(2);
```

Comment: This would make sense, but the function is actually `constexpr void remove_prefix(size_type)`. Can you ever use a method whose only purpose is to mutate an existing object, in a constexpr?

Comment: @Useless The code in my answer does precisely that. I agree it's weird.

Comment: So it does! I completely misread your free function. It doesn't actually work for me in GCC7.1, but I guess it's early days for 1z.

Comment: @Useless Yeah, I noticed that too - libstdc++'s implementation of `remove_prefix()` isn't marked `constexpr`.

Comment: `constexpr` implies `const`, does it not? So `std::string_view::remove_prefix()` should not be able to modify itself?

Comment: @inetknght No it does not. A `constexpr` member function does not need to be a `const` member function.